# D3.js use hardcode json to implement treemap wrong(Just COPY the demo code and it failed)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, treemap

I am new to know D3.js, and I try to use the treemap of it, and I copy the demo code and change the link of outer json file to hardcode, and when I run it, it met a problem. Here is the original demo and tutorial:
https://secure.polisci.ohio-state.edu/faq/d3/zoomabletreemap_code.php
and the link to the demo is at the bottom of this page.

And here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/cR35x/2/

To load the hardcode json, I changed this function, please pay attention here:

```
    var json = [......];
    d3.json(json, function(root) {
    root = json;
    initialize(root);
    accumulate(root);
    layout(root);
    display(root);
    .......
```

It didn't show the right thing as the demo. Could someone give me any help? Thanks!

Another question, when I run it locally without any server with chrome, just like the url:

file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/treemap/treemap.html

It shows nothing but a gray square, without any words or links on it. And for chrome, I have already set the tag: allow-file-access-from-files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because my friend, the example you've posted uses `d3.v2` whereas in your fiddle you are using `d3.v3`.

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/cR35x/9/) with working example using `d3.v2`.

In case you are interested: Implementation of the `layout` function is different in `v2` and `v3`. And, since you were using `v3`, the children elements of the json objects were not getting parsed and only the top level children were being rendered.

Also, since the data has been hard-coded within the file, this should now also work when you directly open it in chrome via `file://` protocol.

Comment: Thank you, that really works, and I also tried d3.v3 in jsfiddle, it can also work. So I think my problem can be solved only change the d3.json() method!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose `d3.json(filename, function)` is to read a file and do something with the data. The first parameter has to be a filename.  If you already have your data loaded as a Javascript object, you don't need to use `d3.json`.  Just do something with the data.

Comment: Yes, you are also very right, but because the upper person answer the problem before you, so I should choose to accept him. Also, thank you so much!

Comment: Ah, well @srvikram13 figured out your main problem which wasn't related to the `d3.json` method at all.

Comment: haha, that's true your answer is more exactly, and @srvikram fixed that method but didn't mention that. So I should say because of both of your answers, I find that problem. While, stackoverflow can not choose multiple accepted answers. Thank you so much, hope you not mind this.

Comment: No problem.  I'm not desperate for points.  But you can vote up multiple answers even if only one can be accepted.